# OUT_OF_SERVICE VS DOWN health status (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, health-monitoring

I couldn't find it documented anywhere... when to use which?

My wild guess is that `Status.OUT_OF_SERVICE` means that the service is deliberately shut down, while `Status.DOWN` means that the service is unhealthy (not necessarily unavailable, it just should be looked at).

Answer (score 2):

The docs
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_writing_custom_healthindicators give an example of a custom order severity. The default OrderedHealthAggregator uses an order like this

```
Status.DOWN, Status.OUT_OF_SERVICE, Status.UP, Status.UNKNOWN
```

So spring boot considers DOWN more "severe" than OUT_OF_SERVICE. By default both map to HTTP 503 Service Unavailable for the /health endpoint. So really out of the box if you use either you will see the same behavior. None of the spring provided health indicators use OUT_OF_SERVICE. They just use DOWN.

Answer (score 0):

If believe the Javadoc for `org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Status` answers this:

(Although I also think the documentation in this area could be improved with some examples.)

```
/**
 * {@link Status} indicating that the component or subsystem has suffered an
 * unexpected failure.
 */
public static final Status DOWN = new Status("DOWN");

/**
 * {@link Status} indicating that the component or subsystem has been taken out of
 * service and should not be used.
 */
public static final Status OUT_OF_SERVICE = new Status("OUT_OF_SERVICE");
```

As you correctly guessed, `DOWN` is unexpected downtime whereas `OUT_OF_SERVICE` means a service was deliberately shut down.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is a bit incorrect. Both `DOWN` and `OUT_OF_SERVICE` are statuses of the various components in spring actuator realm. In simple terms:

- `DOWN` means that the component is unavailble
- `OUT_OF_SERVICE` means that the component is not yet ready

Use whatever status makes sense in your case, [but in general both of these statuses will return 503 to the http callee by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#writing-custom-healthindicators). So the difference is mainly for description purposes.

For debuggers out there - out of my own experiance, I will say that most of the time in spring boot itself you will expriance the `OUT_OF_SERVICE` status becuase of the [readinessState probe](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/25/liveness-and-readiness-probes-with-spring-boot). In order to check it and verify the source of the problem you can set this property:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Or you can request the readinessState prob directly via `/actuator/health/readiness`, but I'd prefer the first approach since it provides a lot of debugging info so you will identify the cause sooner.

P.S: If the readiness probe is in the `OUT_OF_SERVICE` state, then you need to check that all of your synchronous:

- `EventListener`-s
- `ApplicationRunner`-s
- `CommandLineRunner`-s etc

are finished successfuly. If any of them block the current thread, then spring will consider that the application is not yet ready, and will constantly return `OUT_OF_SERVICE` for readinessProbe until thread is released.